# How to resolve "Cannot read property 'should' of undefined" in chai?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to test my test my RESTful nodejs API but keep running into the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'should' of undefined
```

I'm using the restify framework for my API.

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Customer = require('../src/models/customerSchema');

const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const server = require('../src/app');
const should = chai.should();

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Customers', () => {
   describe('/getCustomers', () => {
       it('it should GET all the customers', (done) => {
           chai.request(server)
               .get('/getCustomers')
               .end((err, res) => {
                   res.should.have.status(200);
                   res.body.should.be.a('array');
                   done();
                });
       });
   });
});
```

The testing works fine when I remove the line `res.body.should.be.a('array');`
Is there anyway I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Normally, when you suspect a value might be `undefined` or `null`, you would wrap the value in a call to `should()`, e.g. `should(res.body)`, since referencing any property on `null` or `undefined` results in an exception.

However, Chai uses an old version of `should` that doesn't support this, so you need to assert the existence of the value beforehand.

Instead, add one more assertion:

```
should.exist(res.body);
res.body.should.be.a('array');
```

Chai uses an old/outdated version of `should`, so the usual `should(x).be.a('array')` won't work.

---

Alternatively, you can use the official [`should`](https://npmjs.org/package/should) package directly:

```
$ npm install --save-dev should
```

and use it as a drop-in replacement:

```
const should = require('should');

should(res.body).be.a('array');
```

Comment: Now I'm getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: should is not a function`.

Comment: Change `const should = chai.should();` to `const should = chai.should;`.

Comment: I changed the line as you said but now I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined`. My code is `res.should.have.status(200); should(res.body).be.a('array');`

Comment: @BattleFrog Chai uses a stripped down version of `should`. See my updated answer (disregard my last comment - keep the parenthesis, you do need them).

Comment: `chai.should().exist(...)`.should.work ([doc](http://chaijs.com/guide/styles/#should-extras))